# How to select the data from mqsql table with half of data

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting data from form field. It contains

```
$city = "blr";
$field = "name";
$value= "mohai";


$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT u.*, ad.*, ut.*, ci.*, st.* FROM user u, address ad, user_types ut, city ci, state st WHERE u.city_id=ci.id and ci.state_id=st.id and u.userId=ad.userId and 
    u.userType=ut.id and ci.city_name='".$city."' and u.".$field."='".$value."' and u.isDelete = '0'");
```

I am using above query for getting all data.
Here my question is

user table has name field

For ex: the data is in user table-> "mohaideen"

If i give the name field mohai. It should filter the data from table.

How can i write a query for above functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To search through a pattern use % sign in sql .
your query would be some thing like below

```
select from Table_name where some_property like modhi%;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE in your query to match the string

```
          $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT u.*, ad.*, ut.*, ci.*, st.* FROM user u, address ad, user_types ut, city ci, state st WHERE u.city_id=ci.id and ci.state_id=st.id and u.userId=ad.userId and 
u.userType=ut.id and ci.city_name='".$city."' and u.".$field." LIKE '%".$value."%' and u.isDelete = '0'");
```

Answer (score 0):

For matching wildcards in query you can use LIKE clause

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT u.*, ad.*, ut.*, ci.*, st.* FROM user u, address ad, user_types ut, city ci, state st WHERE u.city_id=ci.id and ci.state_id=st.id and u.userId=ad.userId and 
u.userType=ut.id and ci.city_name='".$city."' and u.".$field." LIKE '%".$value."%' and u.isDelete = '0'");
```

Answer (score 0):

> For this u have to use **LIKE** keyword in your query
>
> Here is a good example
>
> Refer this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-like-clause.htm)